# Matlab 7.0.1 error

Tags: matlab

whenever I try to start MATLAB I get the following message:"the specified module could not be found" and then the following error report in command window.

```
To get started, select MATLAB Help or Demos from the Help menu.


------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Thu Nov 03 19:26:52 2011
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Configuration:
  MATLAB Version:   7.0.1.24704 (R14) Service Pack 1
  MATLAB License:   203363
  Operating System: Microsoft Windows XP
  Window System:    Version 5.1 (Build 2600: Service Pack 3)
  Processor ID:     x86 Family 6 Model 7 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine:  Java 1.4.2_04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java
HotSpot(TM) Client VM
    (mixed mode)
  Default Charset:  ibm-5348_P100-1997

Register State:
  EAX = 00000000  EBX = 00000000
  ECX = 7c8099fd  EDX = 05290001
  ESI = 0120b1c0  EDI = 01413220
  EBP = 00cda3e4  ESP = 00cda354
  EIP = 00000000  FLG = 00010212

Stack Trace:
  [0]
numerics.dll:??$mfGenMatrixMult@N@@YAXPAUmxArray_tag@@00W4MM_Transpose@@1N@Z(0x01413620,
0x01413220, 0x01413660, 0) + 532 bytes
  [1] numerics.dll:void __cdecl mfGenMatrixMult(struct mxArray_tag
*,struct mxArray_tag *,struct mxArray_tag *,enum MM_Transpose,enum
MM_Transpose)(0x01413620, 0x01413220, 0x01413660, 0) + 120 bytes
  [2] numerics.dll:void __cdecl mfTimesTransposeFcn2DFloatPt(int,struct
mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00cda598,
6, 0x00cda508) + 913 bytes
  [3] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall Mfh_builtin<struct
mxArray_tag>::dispatch_mf(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *)(1, 0x00cda598, 3, 0x00cda508) + 55 bytes
  [4] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_MATLAB_fn::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *)(1, 0x00cda598, 3, 0x00cda508) + 200 bytes
  [5] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl
inJitCallMatlabFunctionPtrNoDestroy(class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *,int,int,struct
mxArray_tag * * const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0x01357ec0, 323,
1, 0x00cda598) + 132 bytes
  [6] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl accelExec(struct _accelBytecode *,enum
inMarshalType *)(0x0120b1b0, 0x00cda774, 0xffffffff, 0) + 17027 bytes
  [7] m_interpreter.dll:_inExecuteHotSegment(0x00cda7a8, 0x00cda8d4,
0x00cda884, 0) + 1542 bytes
  [8] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *)(1,
3651, 95, 0) + 377 bytes
  [9] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *)(1, 3651, 35,
0) + 272 bytes
  [10] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class
Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x09faa7f0, 0, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 778 bytes
  [11] m_interpreter.dll:_inWordsj(0, 0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 443 bytes
  [12] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::inRunMP(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag *
*,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 158 bytes
  [13] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cdb34c, 2) + 28
bytes
  [14] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 26 bytes
  [15] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 273 bytes
  [16] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl mdCallFunction(int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *)(0,
0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) + 56 bytes
  [17] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
ResolverFunctionDesc::CallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * *
const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00cdb34c, 2, 0x00cdb3dc) +
236 bytes
  [18] m_interpreter.dll:public: bool __thiscall
Resolver::CallMFunction(int,int,class _m_operand * const,union
m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage
*,int *)(0, 1, 0x01412ce0, 0) + 1041 bytes
  [19] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl inResolveMFunctionCall(struct
_m_function_desc *,int,int,class _m_operand * const,union
m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage
*,int *,enum inMarshalType *,unsigned int,int,unsigned int const
*,int)(0x0a3d09b0, 0, 1, 0x01412ce0) + 148 bytes
  [20] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl accelMFunctionCall(struct _accelOp
*,struct _accelOp * *,struct _accelBytecode *,int *,enum inMarshalType
*)(0x09e816e0, 0x00cdb9fc, 0x0120aa40, 0x00cdb9e8) + 108 bytes
  [21] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl accelExec(struct _accelBytecode
*,enum inMarshalType *)(0x0120aa40, 0x00cdba74, 0, 12) + 18836 bytes
  [22] m_interpreter.dll:_inExecuteHotSegment(0x00cdbaa8, 0x00cdbb04,
0x00cdbaf4, 0x00cdc520) + 1542 bytes
  [23] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class
Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x09fb5c40, 0, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 615 bytes
  [24] m_interpreter.dll:_inWordsj(0, 0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 443 bytes
  [25] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::inRunMP(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag *
*,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 158 bytes
  [26] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cdc490, 1) + 28
bytes
  [27] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 26 bytes
  [28] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 273 bytes
  [29] m_interpreter.dll:void __cdecl mdCallFunction(int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class Mfh_MATLAB_fn *)(0,
0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) + 56 bytes
  [30] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
ResolverFunctionDesc::CallFunction(int,struct mxArray_tag * *
const,int,struct mxArray_tag * * const)(0, 0x00cdc490, 1, 0x00cdc520) +
236 bytes
  [31] m_interpreter.dll:public: bool __thiscall
Resolver::CallMFunction(int,int,class _m_operand * const,union
m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage
*,int *)(0, 1, 0x014121a0, 0) + 1041 bytes
  [32] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl inResolveMFunctionCall(struct
_m_function_desc *,int,int,class _m_operand * const,union
m_operand_storage *,int,class _m_operand * const,union m_operand_storage
*,int *,enum inMarshalType *,unsigned int,int,unsigned int const
*,int)(0x0a3d0b40, 0, 1, 0x014121a0) + 148 bytes
  [33] m_interpreter.dll:bool __cdecl accelMFunctionCall(struct _accelOp
*,struct _accelOp * *,struct _accelBytecode *,int *,enum inMarshalType
*)(0x09f76e10, 0x00cdcb40, 0x0120aa20, 0x00cdcb2c) + 108 bytes
  [34] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl accelExec(struct _accelBytecode
*,enum inMarshalType *)(0x0120aa20, 0x00cdcbb8, 0xffffffff, 0) + 18836
bytes
  [35] m_interpreter.dll:_inExecuteHotSegment(0x00cdcbec, 0x00cdcd18,
0x00cdccc8, 0) + 1542 bytes
  [36] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *)(1,
421, 50, 0) + 377 bytes
  [37] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *)(1, 421, 31,
0) + 272 bytes
  [38] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class
Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x09f68c80, 0, 2, 0x00cdd2d0) + 778 bytes
  [39] m_interpreter.dll:_inWordsj(0, 0x00cdd270, 2, 0x00cdd2d0) + 443 bytes
  [40] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::inRunMP(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag *
*,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cdd270, 2, 0x00cdd2d0) + 158 bytes
  [41] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cdd270, 2) + 28
bytes
  [42] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdd270, 2, 0x00cdd2d0) + 26 bytes
  [43] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdd270, 2, 0x00cdd2d0) + 273 bytes
  [44] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl mdDispatch(int,char const
*,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class
Mfh_MATLAB_fn * *)(462, 0x014c38ec "colordef", 0, 0x00cdd270) + 88 bytes
  [45] m_interpreter.dll:_inDispatchFromStack(462, 0x014c38ec "colordef",
0, 2) + 801 bytes
  [46] m_interpreter.dll:_inCallFcnFromReference(0, 0x00cdde08,
0x789b6a50, 0xcccccccd) + 176 bytes
  [47] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *)(1,
0, 59, 0) + 4160 bytes
  [48] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *)(1, 0, 16, 0)
+ 272 bytes
  [49] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class
Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x09f0fad0, 1, 0, 0x7893a5a0) + 778 bytes
  [50] m_interpreter.dll:_inExecCompScript(0, 0x00cdd9e4, 0x09f0fad0,
0xffffffff) + 327 bytes
  [51] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::inRunMP(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag *
*,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cdd9e4, 0, 0x00cdda44) + 122 bytes
  [52] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cdd9e4, 0) + 28
bytes
  [53] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdd9e4, 0, 0x00cdda44) + 26 bytes
  [54] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cdd9e4, 0, 0x00cdda44) + 273 bytes
  [55] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl mdDispatch(int,char const
*,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class
Mfh_MATLAB_fn * *)(461, 0, 0, 0x00cdd9e4) + 88 bytes
  [56] m_interpreter.dll:_inDispatchFromStack(461, 0, 0, 0) + 801 bytes
  [57] m_interpreter.dll:_inCallFcnFromReference(0, 0x09ea1f80,
0x789b6a50, 0xcccccccd) + 176 bytes
  [58] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *)(1,
0, 86, 0) + 4160 bytes
  [59] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *)(1, 0, 18, 0)
+ 272 bytes
  [60] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inExecuteMFunctionOrScript(class
Mfh_mp *,bool)(0x015658e0, 1, 0, 0x7893a5a0) + 778 bytes
  [61] m_interpreter.dll:_inExecCompScript(0, 0x00cde158, 0x015658e0,
0xffffffff) + 327 bytes
  [62] m_interpreter.dll:public: void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::inRunMP(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag *
*,struct inWorkSpace_tag *)(0, 0x00cde158, 0, 0x00cde1b8 "ØáÍ") + 122
bytes
  [63] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(struct _mdUnknown_workspace *,int,struct
mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *)(0, 0, 0x00cde158, 0) + 28
bytes
  [64] m_interpreter.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_mp::dispatch_file(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cde158, 0, 0x00cde1b8 "ØáÍ") + 26 bytes
  [65] m_dispatcher.dll:public: virtual void __thiscall
Mfh_file::dispatch_fh(int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag
* *)(0, 0x00cde158, 0, 0x00cde1b8 "ØáÍ") + 273 bytes
  [66] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl mdDispatch(int,char const
*,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,int,struct mxArray_tag * *,class
Mfh_MATLAB_fn * *)(452, 0x012f3424 "matlabrc", 0, 0x00cde158) + 88 bytes
  [67] m_interpreter.dll:_inDispatchFromStack(452, 0x012f3424 "matlabrc",
0, 0) + 801 bytes
  [68] m_interpreter.dll:enum opcodes __cdecl inDispatchCall(char const
*,int,int,int,int *,int *)(0x012f3424 "matlabrc", 452, 0, 0) + 138 bytes
  [69] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterp(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag volatile *)(0,
0, 0, 0) + 2359 bytes
  [70] m_interpreter.dll:int __cdecl inInterPcodeSJ(enum
inDebugCheck,int,int,enum opcodes,struct inPcodeNest_tag *)(0, 0, 0, 0)
+ 272 bytes
  [71] m_interpreter.dll:_inInterPcode(0, 0x78773d54, 0, 0) + 69 bytes
  [72] m_interpreter.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl
in_local_call_eval_function(int *,struct _pcodeheader *,int *,struct
mxArray_tag * * const,enum inDebugCheck)(0x00cded74, 0x00cdee60, 0,
0x78fdea78 "C:\Documents and Settings\BORCA\..") + 162 bytes
  [73] m_interpreter.dll:$L73181(0x78773d54, 0x79c91170 "matlabrc", 0, 0)
+ 196 bytes
  [74] m_interpreter.dll:enum inExecutionStatus __cdecl
inEvalCmdWithLocalReturnandtype(char const *,int *,enum
inDebugCheck)(0x79c91170 "matlabrc", 0, 0, 1) + 69 bytes
  [75] m_interpreter.dll:_inEvalCmd(0x79c91170 "matlabrc", 0x09e6ec50, 0,
0x014c76d0) + 17 bytes
  [76] bridge.dll:_mnRunLoginScript(0x014c7ef8, 0x7931276e, 0, 0x014c7f30
" T@") + 401 bytes
  [77] bridge.dll:int __cdecl
mnRunPathDependentInitialization(void)(0x014c7ef8, 0, 0x014c7f30 " T@",
0x00cdf4fb) + 17 bytes
  [78] mcr.dll:public: __thiscall mcrInstance::mcrInstance(class
mcrOptions &,class MfileReader *)(0x00cdff04, 0x004c7f30, 336780,
0x4d5c3a43) + 373 bytes
  [79] MATLAB.exe:0x00401c86(4194304, 0, 336780, 0x014c7ef8)
  [80] MATLAB.exe:0x00403e45(3473458, 3407922, 0x7ffdb000, 0x8054b6ed)
  [81] kernel32.dll:0x7c817067(0x00403cc0 "jth8U@", 0, 200, 319)

Please follow these steps in reporting this problem to The MathWorks so
that we have the best chance of correcting it:

  1. Send this crash report to segv@mathworks.com for automated analysis.
     For your convenience, this information has been recorded in:
       C:\DOCUME~1\BORCA\LOCALS~1\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.3240

  2. Also, if the problem is reproducible, send the crash report to
     support@mathworks.com along with:
       - A specific list of steps that will reproduce the problem
       - Any M, MEX, MDL or other files required to reproduce the problem
       - Any error messages displayed to the command window
     A technical support engineer will contact you with further information.

Thank you for your assistance.  Please save your workspace and restart
MATLAB before continuing your work.

Error in ==> whitebg at 96
lum = [.298936021 .58704307445 .114020904255]*c';

Error in ==> colordef>wdefault at 103
whitebg(fig,[1 1 1])

Error in ==> colordef at 50
  wdefault(fig)

Error in ==> hgrc at 59
colordef(0,'white') % Set up for white defaults

Error in ==> matlabrc at 86
hgrc
```

Does anybody know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Tnx

Comment: Do you send the crash record mail to segv@mathworks.com?

Comment: I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to request support installation and execution of a Mathworks product.  They have great customer support and you should use it.

Answer (score 3):

**Have you tried what it says in your error message?**

"Please follow these steps in reporting this problem to The MathWorks so
    that [they] have the best chance of correcting it:

1. Send this crash report to [segv@mathworks.com](http://mailto%3asegv@mathworks.com) for automated analysis.
        For your convenience, this information has been recorded in:
          `C:\DOCUME~1\BORCA\LOCALS~1\Temp\matlab_crash_dump.3240`
2. Also, if the problem is reproducible, send the crash report to
    support@mathworks.com along with:

   - A specific list of steps that will reproduce the problem
   - Any M, MEX, MDL or other files required to reproduce the problem
   - Any error messages displayed to the command window
      A technical support engineer will contact you with further information.

Thank you for your assistance.  Please save your workspace and restart
    MATLAB before continuing your work."

*I doubt you'll get a better answer here, I'm afraid.*

**Other things you can try**

- renaming your matlabrc.m (which caused the error)
- comment out the line #86 in matlabrc.m  containing the offending command `hgrc` 
  ... but I doubt that will solve your problem.
- try a fresh reinstall...